# Where is my package installed?

Tags: centos, centos7, pytest

I have installed pytest in my centos 7. But when I am trying to check for the version, it is giving the following error:

```
$ pip install pytest
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.4.25 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest)
$ pytest --version
-bash: pytest: command not found
```

I am new to Centos . Can someone please help me figure out what the problem is. I googled, but didn't get any clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able run the command 'locate bin/pytest' in order to locate the pytest script.

example from my install:
locate bin/pytest

Returns:
/usr/bin/pytest

Comment: A problem with `locate` is that it uses `locate.db` which is updated nightly (with `updatedb` script). If `pytest` was installed just a minute ago `locate` misses it.

Comment: I agree.  I found it useful to launch updatedb manually when I am unable to find a file after performing a recent install.   The updatedb does not require much overhead on my servers so running it manually is not a big issue here.